# Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\SuscribersList] - Laravel - Seeds

Tags: php, laravel

Un saludo,

Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer un factory para generar falsos registros pero me arroja el error publicado en el titulo:

```
InvalidArgumentException  : Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\SuscribersList].
```

**Cabe destacar que mi modelo lo tengo creado:**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SuscribersList extends Model
{
    //
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_list';

    protected $table = 'suscribers_list';

    protected $fillable = [
        'list_name', 'list_type', 'user_id'
    ];
}
```

**Y estoy llamando correctamente la clase en los seeds:**

```html
<?php

use App\SuscribersList;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SuscribersListSeed extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {   
       
        factory(SuscribersList::class, 17)->create();
    }
}
```

**Así llamo mis clases desde el `composer.json`**

```html
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

Adicionalmente probé de otras soluciones recomendadas lanzar un composer dump-autoload pero no funcionó.

Cabe destacar que soy novato con Laravel por lo que de seguro el error es bastante simple de corregir.

**Mi versión de Laravel:**

```
$ php artisan -V
Laravel Framework 6.5.1
```

A continuación coloco el error completo que me arroja la `terminal`

```html
InvalidArgumentException : Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\SuscribersList]. at C:\miProyecto\Miel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:269 265| */ 266| protected function getRawAttributes(array
$attributes = []) 267| { 268| if (! isset($this->definitions[$this->class][$this->name])) { > 269| throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to locate factory with name [{$this->name}] [{$this->class}]."); 270| } 271| 272| $definition = call_user_func(
273| $this->definitions[$this->class][$this->name], Exception trace: 1 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::getRawAttributes([]) C:\miProyecto\Miel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:292 2 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
C:\miProyecto\Miel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php:116 Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

**Creo que la pregunta salta a la vista, ¿Qué error tengo que no puedo ejecutar mi seed? :-(**

Comment: Eso no lo hago yo, lo hace Laravel por defecto. Solo lo coloco como anexo para mostrar que las rutas se están llamando correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tenia como estaba llamando la clase en el archivo `SuscribersListFactory.php`

Lo estaba llamando de esta manera

```html
use App\Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        'list_name' => $faker->sentence(2),
    ];
});
```

En vez de llamarlo de la forma correcta que es así:

```html
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\SuscribersList::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        'list_name' => $faker->sentence(2),
    ];
});
```